# Procedure or function 'InsertUser' expects parameter '@Username', which was not supplied

Tags: c#

I am getting error message

> Procedure or function 'InsertUser' expects parameter '@Username', which was not supplied

Please help me to solve this.

My stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUser] (
    @Username varchar(50), 
    @Password varchar(50)
)
AS 
    INSERT INTO logform(Username, Password) 
    VALUES(@Username, @Password)
```

My connection class

```
public class connection
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;

    public connection()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=SEMIL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=semil;Integrated security=true");
        cmd = null;
    }

    public void nonquery(string qry)
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

My class

```
public class master
{
    connection conn = new connection();

    SqlCommand cmd = null;

    public void insert(string username, string password)
    {
        string qry = "InsertUser";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("qry");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =username;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =password;
        conn.nonquery(qry);
    }
}
```

My button click function

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       mas.insert(txtuser.Text, txtpass.Text);

       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('logged in');", true);
}
```

Please help Me.......thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating a command (with `"qry"` as the query instead of a real query), and setting parameters, then entirely ignore it and call your own `nonquery` method which creates a new command and **doesn't set parameters at all**?

Comment: oh am sorry Sir...and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see inside the `executenonquery` method of the `connection` class this line?

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
```

This creates a new command, one without any parameters defined. Of course it fails.

The fastest way to fix your code is to change the method `executenonquery` to receive a already built command or create an overload for it

```
public void nonquery(SqlCommand cmd)
{
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

}
```

and pass the command that you build in the insert method of the master class

```
public class master
{
    connection conn = new connection();

    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    public void insert(string username, string password)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertUser");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =username;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =password;
        conn.nonquery(cmd);

    }
}
```

Comment: I dnt know your name and who you are..Eventhough am thanking you...I never forget you sir,..Thank you very much..Its working properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be a disjoint between your `master` / `connection` classes. In `master` you setup the command, configure the parameters, and then you pass `qry`  down into `connection` which creates *another* command (with no parameters).

It looks like what you are *trying* to do here is a re-use the `SqlConnection` instance therefore you should pass `cmd` to `connection` instead e.g.

**master**

```
public void insert(string username, string password)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertUser");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =username;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =password;
    conn.nonquery(cmd);
}
```

**connection**

```
public void nonquery(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Alternatively you could look at making `nonquery` more generic and allow for parameters to be passed in e.g.

```
public void nonquery(string sql, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, CommandType type = CommandType.Text)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.Select(x => new SqlParameter(x.Key, x.Value)));
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
...
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>(2)
{
    { "@Username", username },
    { "@Password", password }
};
nonquery("InsertUser", parameters, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

This would make it reusable for other commands as well

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>(1)
{
    { "@Username", username }
};
nonquery("select * from user where Username = @Username", parameters);
```

Comment: @steve How can we write the connection class in the case of executereader()???

Comment: @SemilSebastian are you asking steve in conjunction with this answer or are you asking me?